# FFMPEG: extract 1 frame from an array of times

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a timeline of images for a video using `FFMPEG.wasm`. The times I want to pass in is 1/10 its total duration.

I tried:

```
const duration = video.current.duration;
const fps = duration / 10;

//this is the command I used on the CLI for a 1 hour video.
ffmpeg -skip_frame nokey -i temp.mp4 -vf "scale=180:-1,fps=1/600" out%d.png
```

but the output is really slow when it comes to long videos due to FFMPEG having to go through the entire video.

Is there a command that's like:

`ffmpeg -ss "600, 1200, 1800 ... 6000" -i temp.mp4 -vf scale=180:-1 -frames:v 1 out%d.png`

where it only outputs an image only at those specific times without having to loop the FFMPEG command 10 times?

Comment: Look into `select` filter.

Comment: @kesh Just tried a few of them and they're still not fast enough. FFMPEG still goes through the entire video.

Comment: The timing must be really sparse. I'd just call one frame at a time (spawn as many ffmpeg subprocesses as needed). That being said, I'd make sure that the slow down is due to demuxing and not scaling or muxing. If the latters are the reason, then you're hunting for a wrong target.

Comment: Also, just to make sure, did you run the `select` filter first? That is `-vf select=...,scale=...,fps=...` . If not you were scaling every frame.

Comment: Was I supposed to put fps in? Since I'm already selecting the frames, calling fps would be redundant, no? I tried both combinations. `select` first and then `scale`. Can't say I notice a difference. Worse comes to worst, I just have to brute force it with the loop.

Comment: Donno, you have `fps` in your op. (shouldn't impact performance anyway.) Another thing you can try to gauge is to output to a null device (`-f null -`) to see if how much time png muxing is taking. (frames are pretty small but they must be written to disk.) Finally, you can call several ffmpeg processes asynchronously to speed up the process over sequential loop (they will fight for disk access, so likely not too many).